# ng-model versus getElementById

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-model

I am reading the book "Pro AngularJS" by Adam Freeman, Apress.

He creates an app that is a to-do list and you can add your own things on the list. In the part "Responding to User Interaction", page 34

Here is the model

```
var model = {
  user: "Adam",
  items: [{ action: "Buy Flowers", done: false },
  { action: "Get Shoes", done: false },
  { action: "Collect Tickets", done: true },
  { action: "Call Joe", done: false }]
};
```

the app

```
var todoApp = angular.module("todoApp", []);
```

the controller

```
todoApp.controller("ToDoCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.todo = model;
  $scope.addNewItem = function (actionText) {
    $scope.todo.items.push({ action: actionText, done: false });
  }
});
```

the input field

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="actionText" />
```

and the button that adds new things in the model

```
<button ng-click="addNewItem(actionText)">Add</button>
```

And then he comments this line `<input class="form-control" ng-model="actionText" />` (pp 36)

> I have specified the name of a property for the directive to update
>   that is not part of the model. The ng-model directive will dynamically
>   create the property for me within the scope of the controller,
>   effectively creating dynamic model properties that are used to handle
>   user input.

What does he mean by

> creating dynamic model properties that are used to
>   handle user input.

?

Do we add a new property to the model named `actionText` ? . We add a ""pseudo""-property so the controller can use it to grab an input value?

If this is the case, then why use `ng-model="actionText"` and not just use plain old `getElementById`? After all we only need the value of the field.

Can something like `ng-click getElementById("myInput").value` do the trick and also avoid adding unwanted stuff to the model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the features of angularjs is to abstract as much as possible the manual javascript manipulation of the DOM.

Imagine having 10 fields on a form and having to do getElementById…..It’s much simpler in angularjs. You just need to have ng-model in each input type and on your controller methods you just use your model.  You don't even have to pass them as arguments; the method on the controller will have access to the model.

I think that using ng-model will ultimately generate a cleaner code than using getElementById to access each field value.